# Jquery mouseenter animation - mouseleave too quickly

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

Please take a look of this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CQG4L/1/embedded/result/

I have created a queue of animations on mouseenter and mouseleave events.

You'll notice that strange things happen if you mouseover/mouseout too quickly.
In fact, this part of mouseleave code

```
$(this).find(".back_content img").fadeOut("fast");
$(this).find(".back_content .text_content").fadeOut("fast");
```

is not executed.

I've searched around about this issue, and found that stop() is a possible solution. I have tried to apply stop but there's not difference at all

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide")
        .on("mouseenter",

    function () {
        $(this).find(".front_content").stop(true,true).animate({
            top: "-=88px",
        }, 300, function () {
            $(this).fadeOut("fast");
            $(this).parent().find(".back_content img").fadeIn("fast");
            $(this).parent().find(".back_content .text_content").fadeIn("fast");
        });
    })
        .on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).find(".back_content img").fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).find(".back_content .text_content").fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).find(".front_content").fadeIn("fast");
        $(this).find(".front_content").animate({
            top: "+=88px",
        }, 300);

    });
});
```

I've tested this by applying stop() on all transistions, or some of them. Still not working ok.

Comment: how do you apply stop? show the code you made to get desired effect.

Comment: $(this).find(".front_content").stop().animate({....});

Comment: Perhaps using css-animations might be an option (if you don't have to deal with backwards compatibility). I've tried a number of things, but there's always something (e.g. I tried using `$(..).queue()` to ensure animation run one after the other, which gave an interesting yoyo effect when moueenters and mouseleaves build up). My latest effort is http://jsfiddle.net/jrYDb/ but it still very occasionally fails to trigger a final mouseleave.

Comment: I've tried to use queue() too without success. Your code is by far more complex and clever that mine though! Thank you for your time and efford. Yes, it fails to detect mouseleave sometimes, but still there's a major improvement.